# Java Securing network traffic

Tags: java

First of all, I have googled how to secure network traffic and I have found a lot of answers... Only the issue is that I've found too many examples and methods and the majority of the them are very old (> 10 years), so it worries me a little bit.

What I want to know is how I could encrypt network traffic between a server and a client.

I have had a bachelor degree class about it and from what I understand, I need a private-public key pair to encrypt and decrypt. However I may have missed some important notion, because I've got this question currently about that: How can I send the key over the network when that key is the key with which you need to secure the network? Do I even have to deal with it, or are there built-in applications of secure networking in Java?

What I also have seen in class was that the instructors needed to manually verify some key codes to be 100% sure that some person was sending a message (manually as in looking at someone else's screen and comparing the keys to see if they were indeed the same).

I am using sockets currently, and I am not even sure if networking can even be done differently in Java. I would like to know how I could achieve secure networking.

Any links to relevant material are appreciated, preferably I want to know the best solution if there happens to be any. If the link/article is dated, then please justify that it can still be used after 5 or 10 years.

Regards.

Comment: If you're building a web service, just deploy it into some container (tomcat, Jetty, etc), and configure that to use an SSL certificate.

Comment: The standard implementation is called [Diffie–Hellman key exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) - this is how SSL works. There are thousands of implementations out there - most (all?) webservers support certificate based authentication out of the box.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clear about it, I'm using a standalone cleint and not a web service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Transport Layer Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Sockets_Layer) (e.g. the [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) library).

If you want to roll your own security, then use [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) to encrypt the data; Java has built-in support or AES, or else you can use the [Bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) library.  Then use [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29) to encrypt the AES key, and send the encrypted key and the AES-encrypted data from the server to the client; the client decrypts the key, then uses the key to decrypt the AES-encrypted data.

[Java AES Tutorial](http://www.code2learn.com/2011/06/encryption-and-decryption-of-data-using.html), [Java RSA Tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/BasicRSAexample.htm)

Comment: You still end up sending the RSA-encrypted AES key over the network, right? Can't the attacker then decrypt the AES key himself aswell? Or is it all 100% safe? In other words: Why **can** the client decrypt the AES key, but an attacker not?

Comment: @skiwi Because RSA is a public-key (or asymmetric) cryptosystem, as opposed to AES which is a private-key (or secret-key or symmetric) cryptosystem; RSA and other public-key cryptosystems are specifically designed to securely send data over unsecured networks. The Wikipedia page on [public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) can explain it better than I can.

Comment: @skiwi Note that public-key cryptography is a lot more computationally expensive than secret-key cryptography, and sometimes also has limits as to the size of data that can be encrypted - this is why you use both public-key and secret-key cryptography to send a message, instead of only using public-key cryptography.